# compressed json in java

Tags: java, javascript, json

I receive compressed Json as a String in Java. Compressed json is in the format below:

```
[{
    "name": ["alex", "colt", "bolt"],
    "pos": ["AUS", "USA", "UAE"]
}]
```

How I can store the data into bean so that I can then insert it into a database table (in the correct order, e.g. for name : alex then pos = AUS)?

[Here is how I compress the Json](http://mainroach.blogspot.in/2013/08/json-compression-transpose-binary.html).

If I send the Json data without compressing it, then it is more than 5 MB. It also takes more time. Compression reduces the size. I am struggling to store the data.

Comment: Array order should never change, that's what its an array for. In the database just tore it in a TEXT type of field.

Comment: THis input is not valid JSON. There is a trailing `,` at the end of the third line.

Comment: You've apparently implemented some process for rewriting JSON objects as parallel arrays. Did you try just actually compressing the objects first, with something like gzip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Step :**

Create Bean Class corresponding to JSON , in your scenario your bean class contains 2 data members `List<String> names` and `List<String> position`
and their corresponding getters and setters

**Second Step :**

Use Google's GSON library to convert JSON to Java Object

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
            new FileReader("c:\\file.json"));

        //convert the json string back to object
        YourBeanClass obj = gson.fromJson(br, YourBeanClass.class);
```

**Third Step :**
Your bean Object is in your hands enjoy , do whatever you want to do with that !!